# dpkg/miktex error in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tex, dpkg, miktex

I am getting these warnings which I am unable to solve.

I tried using these :

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a

for i in $(dpkg -l|awk '/^ii/ {print $2}'); 
do     
sudo apt-get --reinstall -y install $i; 
done

for i in $(dpkg -l|awk '/^ii/ {print $2}'); 
do
apt-get --reinstall -y install $i;
for i in $(dpkg -l|awk '/^ii/ {print $2}');
do
apt-get --reinstall -y install $i; done
```

NONE OF WHICH WORKED.

```
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-sil-abyssinica' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libtexlua52:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'texlive-pstricks' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'texlive-science-doc' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'texlive-latex-recommended' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-tlwg-garuda' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'texlive-extra-utils' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'texlive-fonts-extra-doc' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'context-modules' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libexiv2-14:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-mathjax' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gsfonts-x11' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-tlwg-kinnari-ttf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'texlive-lang-korean' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-tlwg-typist' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'texlive-lang-indic' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libexpat1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libexpat1:i386' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'texlive-lang-cjk' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'texlive-lang-greek' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-tlwg-typo-ttf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'texlive-humanities-doc' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libsynctex1:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'texlive-fonts-extra' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-gfs-neohellenic' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-ipafont-gothic' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'texlive-htmlxml' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-stix' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'latexdiff' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-comfortaa' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'texlive-latex-extra' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'texlive-pictures-doc' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'texlive-science' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-tlwg-sawasdee' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-tlwg-typewriter' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gsfonts' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-tlwg-laksaman-ttf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libtext-levenshtein-perl' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-tlwg-typewriter-ttf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bsmi00lp' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-lklug-sinhala' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-dejavu-core' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-lohit-guru' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-linuxlibertine' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-unfonts-core' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-hosny-amiri' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'latex-cjk-korean' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-ipafont-mincho' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-ipaexfont-gothic' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'texlive-plain-extra' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libexttextcat-2.0-0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-tlwg-umpush-ttf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-gfs-porson' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'texlive-pstricks-doc' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'texlive-formats-extra' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'texlive-pictures' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'latex-cjk-common' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-tlwg-purisa' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-guru-extra' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bkai00mp' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libexporter-tiny-perl' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libtext-unidecode-perl' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-lobstertwo' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'texlive-humanities' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-tlwg-umpush' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-oflb-asana-math' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-wqy-microhei' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-lobster' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'texlive-publishers' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-gfs-solomos' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-guru' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-freefont-otf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'xfonts-utils' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'texlive-lang-arabic' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'preview-latex-style' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libexempi3:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gkai00mp' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-texgyre' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-horai-umefont' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'texlive-full' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-crosextra-carlito' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-tlwg-typist-ttf' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'texlive-font-utils' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'fonts-noto-cjk' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'texlive-binaries' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed...lot others
```

**This is the Miktex Error which also isn't getting resolved.**

```
Setting up miktex (2.9.6530-1) ...
*** Error in `initexmf': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x0000000000de48c0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777e5)[0x7f9cad0b57e5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x8037a)[0x7f9cad0be37a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4c)[0x7f9cad0c253c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__cxa_finalize+0x9a)[0x7f9cad07836a]
/usr/bin/../lib/../lib/libMiKTeX209-core.so.2(+0x3b403)[0x7f9cab2f1403]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00435000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2760357                            /usr/bin/initexmf
00634000-00635000 r--p 00034000 08:06 2760357                            /usr/bin/initexmf
00635000-00636000 rw-p 00035000 08:06 2760357                            /usr/bin/initexmf
00db1000-018f4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f9ca0000000-7f9ca0021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9ca0021000-7f9ca4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9ca5c82000-7f9ca5f5a000 r--p 00000000 08:06 2753331                    /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
7f9ca5f5a000-7f9ca6029000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2762100                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
7f9ca6029000-7f9ca6229000 ---p 000cf000 08:06 2762100                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
7f9ca6229000-7f9ca622c000 r--p 000cf000 08:06 2762100                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
7f9ca622c000-7f9ca622e000 rw-p 000d2000 08:06 2762100                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0.8.6
7f9ca622e000-7f9ca622f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9ca622f000-7f9ca6276000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2758280                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5.0.0
7f9ca6276000-7f9ca6475000 ---p 00047000 08:06 2758280                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5.0.0
7f9ca6475000-7f9ca6477000 r--p 00046000 08:06 2758280                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5.0.0
7f9ca6477000-7f9ca6479000 rw-p 00048000 08:06 2758280                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5.0.0
7f9ca6479000-7f9ca647a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9ca647a000-7f9ca6488000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2758275                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1.0.0
7f9ca6488000-7f9ca6687000 ---p 0000e000 08:06 2758275                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1.0.0
7f9ca6687000-7f9ca6688000 r--p 0000d000 08:06 2758275                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1.0.0
7f9ca6688000-7f9ca6689000 rw-p 0000e000 08:06 2758275                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1.0.0
7f9ca6689000-7f9ca66b0000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2758277                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0.0.0
7f9ca66b0000-7f9ca68b0000 ---p 00027000 08:06 2758277                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0.0.0
7f9ca68b0000-7f9ca68b1000 r--p 00027000 08:06 2758277                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0.0.0
7f9ca68b1000-7f9ca68b2000 rw-p 00028000 08:06 2758277                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0.0.0
7f9ca68b2000-7f9ca68b9000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2761335                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
7f9ca68b9000-7f9ca6ab8000 ---p 00007000 08:06 2761335                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
7f9ca6ab8000-7f9ca6ab9000 r--p 00006000 08:06 2761335                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
7f9ca6ab9000-7f9ca6aba000 rw-p 00007000 08:06 2761335                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6.0.4
7f9ca6aba000-7f9ca6acf000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2758250                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18.1.0
7f9ca6acf000-7f9ca6cce000 ---p 00015000 08:06 2758250                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18.1.0
7f9ca6cce000-7f9ca6ccf000 r--p 00014000 08:06 2758250                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18.1.0
7f9ca6ccf000-7f9ca6cd0000 rw-p 00015000 08:06 2758250                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18.1.0
7f9ca6cd0000-7f9ca6d00000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2758273                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4.1.0
7f9ca6d00000-7f9ca6f00000 ---p 00030000 08:06 2758273                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4.1.0
7f9ca6f00000-7f9ca6f01000 r--p 00030000 08:06 2758273                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4.1.0
7f9ca6f01000-7f9ca6f02000 rw-p 00031000 08:06 2758273                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4.1.0
7f9ca6f02000-7f9ca6f03000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9ca6f03000-7f9ca6fa2000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2758257                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8.0.0
7f9ca6fa2000-7f9ca71a1000 ---p 0009f000 08:06 2758257                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8.0.0
7f9ca71a1000-7f9ca71a2000 r--p 0009e000 08:06 2758257                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8.0.0
7f9ca71a2000-7f9ca71a5000 rw-p 0009f000 08:06 2758257                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8.0.0
7f9ca71a5000-7f9ca7229000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2758284                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26.0.0
7f9ca7229000-7f9ca7428000 ---p 00084000 08:06 2758284                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26.0.0
7f9ca7428000-7f9ca742b000 r--p 00083000 08:06 2758284                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26.0.0
7f9ca742b000-7f9ca742e000 rw-p 00086000 08:06 2758284                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26.0.0
7f9ca742e000-7f9ca742f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9ca742f000-7f9ca7437000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2758286                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0.1.0
7f9ca7437000-7f9ca7636000 ---p 00008000 08:06 2758286                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0.1.0
7f9ca7636000-7f9ca7637000 r--p 00007000 08:06 2758286                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0.1.0
7f9ca7637000-7f9ca7638000 rw-p 00008000 08:06 2758286                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0.1.0
7f9ca7638000-7f9ca763b000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 4198964                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1.5
7f9ca763b000-7f9ca783a000 ---p 00003000 08:06 4198964                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1.5
7f9ca783a000-7f9ca783b000 r--p 00002000 08:06 4198964                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1.5
7f9ca783b000-7f9ca783c000 rw-p 00003000 08:06 4198964                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1.5
7f9ca783c000-7f9ca784d000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2758241                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6.5.1
7f9ca784d000-7f9ca7a4d000 ---p 00011000 08:06 2758241                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6.5.1
7f9ca7a4d000-7f9ca7a4e000 r--p 00011000 08:06 2758241                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6.5.1
7f9ca7a4e000-7f9ca7a4f000 rw-p 00012000 08:06 2758241                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6.5.1
7f9ca7a4f000-7f9ca7aa8000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2761890                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0.1.0
7f9ca7aa8000-7f9ca7ca7000 ---p 00059000 08:06 2761890                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0.1.0
7f9ca7ca7000-7f9ca7cb1000 r--p 00058000 08:06 2761890                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0.1.0
7f9ca7cb1000-7f9ca7cb3000 rw-p 00062000 08:06 2761890                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0.1.0
7f9ca7cb3000-7f9ca7cf0000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2758288                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3.0.0
7f9ca7cf0000-7f9ca7ef0000 ---p 0003d000 08:06 2758288                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3.0.0
7f9ca7ef0000-7f9ca7ef1000 r--p 0003d000 08:06 2758288                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3.0.0
7f9ca7ef1000-7f9ca7ef3000 rw-p 0003e000 08:06 2758288                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3.0.0
7f9ca7ef3000-7f9ca7ef4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9ca7ef4000-7f9ca7f0d000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2762041                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2.0.25
7f9ca7f0d000-7f9ca810d000 ---p 00019000 08:06 2762041                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2.0.25
7f9ca810d000-7f9ca810e000 r--p 00019000 08:06 2762041                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2.0.25
7f9ca810e000-7f9ca810f000 rw-p 0001a000 08:06 2762041                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2.0.25
7f9ca810f000-7f9ca8126000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 4203133                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.23.so
7f9caa181000-7f9caa182000 rw-p 0001b000 08:06 2753272                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1
7f9caa182000-7f9caa1b3000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2755240                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11.6.15
7f9caa1b3000-7f9caa3b3000 ---p 00031000 08:06 2755240                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11.6.15
7f9caa3b3000-7f9caa3b4000 r--p 00031000 08:06 2755240                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11.6.15
7f9caa3b4000-7f9caa3b5000 rw-p 00032000 08:06 2755240                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn.so.11.6.15
7f9caa3b5000-7f9caa3c7000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2758673                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmspack.so.0.1.0
7f9caa3c7000-7f9caa5c6000 ---p 00012000 08:06 2758673                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmspack.so.0.1.0
7f9caa5c6000-7f9caa5c7000 r--p 00011000 08:06 2758673                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmspack.so.0.1.0
7f9caa5c7000-7f9caa5c8000 rw-p 00012000 08:06 2758673                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmspack.so.0.1.0
7f9caa5c8000-7f9caa5d1000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 4203107                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.23.so
7f9caa5d1000-7f9caa7d0000 ---p 00009000 08:06 4203107                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.23.so
7f9caa7d0000-7f9caa7d1000 r--p 00008000 08:06 4203107                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.23.so
7f9caa7d1000-7f9caa7d2000 rw-p 00009000 08:06 4203107                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.23.so
7f9caa7d2000-7f9caa800000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9caa800000-7f9caa803000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 4203114                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f9caa803000-7f9caaa02000 ---p 00003000 08:06 4203114                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f9caaa02000-7f9caaa03000 r--p 00002000 08:06 4203114                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f9caaa03000-7f9caaa04000 rw-p 00003000 08:06 4203114                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
7f9caaa04000-7f9caaa08000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 4198904                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
7f9caaa08000-7f9caac07000 ---p 00004000 08:06 4198904                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
7f9caac07000-7f9caac08000 r--p 00003000 08:06 4198904                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
7f9caac08000-7f9caac09000 rw-p 00004000 08:06 4198904                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1.3.0
7f9caac09000-7f9caac74000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2760679                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.4.0
7f9caac74000-7f9caae74000 ---p 0006b000 08:06 2760679                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.4.0
7f9caae74000-7f9caae77000 r--p 0006b000 08:06 2760679                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.4.0
7f9caae77000-7f9caae78000 rw-p 0006e000 08:06 2760679                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4.4.0
7f9caae78000-7f9caae9e000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 4198802                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0
7f9caae9e000-7f9cab09e000 ---p 00026000 08:06 4198802                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0
7f9cab09e000-7f9cab0a0000 r--p 00026000 08:06 4198802                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0
7f9cab0a0000-7f9cab0a1000 rw-p 00028000 08:06 4198802                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.0
7f9cab0a1000-7f9cab0b4000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2785167                    /usr/lib/libMiKTeX209-extractor.so.6300
7f9cab0b4000-7f9cab2b4000 ---p 00013000 08:06 2785167                    /usr/lib/libMiKTeX209-extractor.so.6300
7f9cab2b4000-7f9cab2b5000 r--p 00013000 08:06 2785167                    /usr/lib/libMiKTeX209-extractor.so.6300
7f9cab2b5000-7f9cab2b6000 rw-p 00014000 08:06 2785167                    /usr/lib/libMiKTeX209-extractor.so.6300
7f9cab2b6000-7f9cab406000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2785166                    /usr/lib/libMiKTeX209-core.so.6413
7f9cab406000-7f9cab605000 ---p 00150000 08:06 2785166                    /usr/lib/libMiKTeX209-core.so.6413
7f9cab605000-7f9cab607000 r--p 0014f000 08:06 2785166                    /usr/lib/libMiKTeX209-core.so.6413
7f9cab607000-7f9cab609000 rw-p 00151000 08:06 2785166                    /usr/lib/libMiKTeX209-core.so.6413
7f9cab609000-7f9cab711000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 4203136                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f9cab711000-7f9cab910000 ---p 00108000 08:06 4203136                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f9cab910000-7f9cab911000 r--p 00107000 08:06 4203136                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f9cab911000-7f9cab912000 rw-p 00108000 08:06 4203136                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
7f9cab912000-7f9cab92a000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 4203108                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f9cab92a000-7f9cabb29000 ---p 00018000 08:06 4203108                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f9cabb29000-7f9cabb2a000 r--p 00017000 08:06 4203108                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f9cabb2a000-7f9cabb2b000 rw-p 00018000 08:06 4203108                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.23.so
7f9cabb2b000-7f9cabb2f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9cabb2f000-7f9cabd49000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 4199481                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
7f9cad408000-7f9cad41e000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 4198941                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f9cad41e000-7f9cad61d000 ---p 00016000 08:06 4198941                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f9cad61d000-7f9cad61e000 rw-p 00015000 08:06 4198941                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f9cad61e000-7f9cad790000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2755340                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f9cad790000-7f9cad990000 ---p 00172000 08:06 2755340                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f9cad990000-7f9cad99a000 r--p 00172000 08:06 2755340                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f9cad99a000-7f9cad99c000 rw-p 0017c000 08:06 2755340                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
7f9cad99c000-7f9cad9a0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9cad9a0000-7f9cada1e000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2785171                    /usr/lib/libMiKTeX209-packagemanager.so.6403
7f9cada1e000-7f9cadc1d000 ---p 0007e000 08:06 2785171                    /usr/lib/libMiKTeX209-packagemanager.so.6403
7f9cadc1d000-7f9cadc1f000 r--p 0007d000 08:06 2785171                    /usr/lib/libMiKTeX209-packagemanager.so.6403
7f9cadc1f000-7f9cadc20000 rw-p 0007f000 08:06 2785171                    /usr/lib/libMiKTeX209-packagemanager.so.6403
7f9cadc20000-7f9cadc2c000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2785177                    /usr/lib/libMiKTeX209-util.so.6405
7f9cadc2c000-7f9cade2b000 ---p 0000c000 08:06 2785177                    /usr/lib/libMiKTeX209-util.so.6405
7f9cade2b000-7f9cade2c000 r--p 0000b000 08:06 2785177                    /usr/lib/libMiKTeX209-util.so.6405
7f9cade2c000-7f9cade2d000 rw-p 0000c000 08:06 2785177                    /usr/lib/libMiKTeX209-util.so.6405
7f9cade2d000-7f9cadf7c000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 2760464                    /usr/lib/libMiKTeX209-core.so.3.25.131
7f9cadf7c000-7f9cae17c000 ---p 0014f000 08:06 2760464                    /usr/lib/libMiKTeX209-core.so.3.25.131
7f9cae17c000-7f9cae17e000 r--p 0014f000 08:06 2760464                    /usr/lib/libMiKTeX209-core.so.3.25.131
7f9cae557000-7f9cae562000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 4199046                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpopt.so.0.0.0
7f9cae562000-7f9cae761000 ---p 0000b000 08:06 4199046                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpopt.so.0.0.0
7f9cae761000-7f9cae762000 r--p 0000a000 08:06 4199046                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpopt.so.0.0.0
7f9cae762000-7f9cae763000 rw-p 0000b000 08:06 4199046                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpopt.so.0.0.0
7f9cae763000-7f9cae789000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 4202586                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f9cae93e000-7f9cae95a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9cae96c000-7f9cae975000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9cae975000-7f9cae97c000 r--s 00000000 08:06 3025437                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
7f9cae97c000-7f9cae988000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f9cae988000-7f9cae989000 r--p 00025000 08:06 4202586                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f9cae989000-7f9cae98a000 rw-p 00026000 08:06 4202586                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
7f9cae98a000-7f9cae98b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffcdc016000-7ffcdc037000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffcdc181000-7ffcdc183000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffcdc183000-7ffcdc185000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

Please I would be very thankful for the help.